# Authenticating headless devices to github

Tags: authentication, github, oauth

My problem is that I want to get deployment information from Github for headless devices. The devices only have ssh & can call REST API. I.e. they do not have  git for example.

There are a number of existing solutions:

- Deployment keys – Requires git executable to be installed and I need to also access Github Container registry
- OAuth App – Tokens have are associated with a real user while the devices are owned by an organization. And having a shared ghost user account has many drawbacks. This would work perfect if the tokens could be owned & managed by an organization.
- Github App – Installation tokens expire after an hour, normal tokens after 10 mins. This means I need a highly reliable server process to create the tokens on the fly and the device is more complicated.

Since deployment keys & OAuth apps use tokens that can be revoked instead of time out, I am curious why this feature is unavailable with Github Apps? After all, for headless devices they just now force you to create a server that authenticates the device and creates a temporary token. This seems more error prone than if they had a long term  token with revocation?

Am I missing something?